# Validation rule for the data entered in custom settings is available?

Tags: customsetting

Currently i am creating custom settings to store some configuration values. But, i wrongly entered some data in that and the data is invalid. Is there any mechanism like validation rule kind of thing available for this, so that the data entered into it is validated before it saves to database.?

Comment: Hi Baskaran, you marked an answer as accepted but it doesn't seem to answer the question. Did it really resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List type of custom settings are not available in validation rules where as Hierarchy type of custom settings are available in validation rules.

Please find the [documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm&language=en_US) and [link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gkDzAAI)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it?  The author was asking whether you can validate custom setting data, not whether you can use custom settings in validation rules.

Comment: This has been marked as accepted but I think perhaps the asker believes that you mean validation rules can be applied to hierarchy settings, which is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way , you can create a validation rule on the Custom settings.To ensure the data entered is correct in your production Org, You need to migrate the custom setting values using Data loader.

If you really want to build a validation rule then the only workaround is to use a custom object but that means the advantages of the Custom Setting is lost (e.g. SOQL call burning)

Comment: This is the best answer.